# Convert first row of pandas dataframe to column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
   0     1     2
0  pass fail  warning
1  50    12    34
```

I am trying to convert first row as column name 
something like this

```
   pass fail  warning
0  50    12    34
```

I am currently doing this by renaming the column name

```
 newdf.rename(columns={0: 'pass', 1: 'fail', 2:'warning'})
```

and then deleting the first row.
Any better way to do it .

Comment: How you get your dataframe? From `read_csv` ? Then remove parameter `header=None`

Comment: nice idea but its sub table of the big table extracted from html file

Comment: So is possible use `df = pd.read_html(url, skiprows=1)` or `df = pd.read_html(url, header=1)` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe need to add parameter to [`read_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html):

```
df = pd.read_html(url, header=1)[0]
```

Or:

```
df = pd.read_html(url, skiprows=1)[0]
```

Comment: This worked import pandas as pd
temp = pd.read_html('report.html',flavor='lxml',header =0)  but I guess i got the idea from your answer

Answer (score 25):

For the dataframe DF, the following line of code will set the first row as the column names of the dataframe:

```
DF.columns = DF.iloc[0]
```

Comment: As a note, this does not drop the first row of the dataframe implicitly, this still needs to be done explicitly.  The skiprows parameter in the pd.read function as per @jezreal seems particularly suited to solve this issue upfront.